# Combo box used in conjunction with a button

Tags: excel, vba

I have a combo box that; when a selection is made, fills a linked cell with that value. I want this process repeated but want the cell directly below filled each time. I have thought to use a button and but am unsure of how to go about creating the macro to make this happen. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"cell directly below"  - I assume you want to change the linked cell to the next row?
This works; the code is commented.

```
Option Explicit

Dim insw& ' global needed because changing the row calls the _Change Sub.
' This is an "in-process" switch.

Sub combobox1Reset() ' reset to B5
  ComboBox1.Clear
  ComboBox1.AddItem "One"
  ComboBox1.AddItem "Two"
  ComboBox1.AddItem "Three"
  insw = 1
  ComboBox1.LinkedCell = Cells(5, 2).Address ' B5
  insw = 0
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
  Dim iRow&, iCol&, s1$, zCell As Range
  If insw Then Exit Sub ' skip row change
  s1 = ComboBox1.LinkedCell ' old addr
  Set zCell = Range(s1) ' get row, col
  iRow = zCell.Row + 1 ' increment
  iCol = zCell.Column
  insw = 1 ' skip row change
  ComboBox1.LinkedCell = Cells(iRow, iCol).Address
  insw = 0
End Sub
```